# Unable to access and delete flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm trying to remove a custom field that is on the opportunity and there are dependencies that I have to remove the field. One of the dependencies is a flow.

- The flow is not activated and currently not in use.

When I click on the field "where is this used", the flow dependency shows up and I can click on the link that takes me to the flow in Flow Builder. However, if I type in `flow` in quick find and pull up the flows, this flow does not show up. I've tried creating a specific list view to display the flow and no matter what I try, the flow will not show up.

- There is no option to delete the flow when it directs me right into Flow Builder.

I cannot figure out why I cannot see the flow when I access flows from the navigation bar.

> Is there a way I can identify where the flow metadata is and how I can
>   remove delete this flow.

Comment: is this possibly an issue between labels and API Names?

Comment: I tried both with no luck...I also tried checking by description and not active. Nothing pulls it back. Yet, I can still pull up the flow. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: If I run this query I see the flow listed and it shows active. However, going to the flow it shows it is deactivated. Strange. Here is the query: `select Id, Label, ApiName, isActive from FlowDefinitionView`

Comment: try switching to classic and then `setup | flows`

Comment: I found it. I was looking for visual flow since the "Where is this used" link on the custom field redirected me to Flow Builder. I assumed it was a visual flow. I checked process builder and there it was. I didn't realize that a process builder would pull up in Flow Builder. I simply missed that. My mistake.

Comment: face plant - I've made this mistake myself. write up an answer